# GeoIP Linux Debian 7

Tags: debian

Доброго времени суток. Может кто может объяснить как установить GeoIP на debian?

> apt-get install php5-geoip

что то установил, но .php файл (с функцией GeoIP) не работает (ничего не показывает). Файл ошибок не выдает. Перепробовал много инструкций из интернета - ничего не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ apt-get install libapache2-mod-geoip geoip-database libgeoip1
$ a2enmod geoip
$ cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/geoip.conf
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
  GeoIPEnable On
  GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
  GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
  GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat MemoryCache
  GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat CheckCache
</IfModule>

$ cd /usr/share/GeoIP/
$ wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
$ gzip -d GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
$ service apache2 restart
$ cat /var/www/index.php
<?php
  #GEOIP_ADDR
  #GEOIP_CONTINENT_CODE
  #GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE
  #GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME

  echo "Country: " . $_SERVER["GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME"];
?>
```